# Get project root path on runtime to read config file

Tags: go, path

I have a Go project with the following structure and Im struggling to read config file which is located in my project,I  need to read the `config yaml` (which inside the root project) and I should read it inside **other package** under `sub root directory` and I got error of **not found**

```
myproject
- config.yaml
- cmd
 --com
  ---ftp
   ----fs.go
```

Inside the `fs.go` I need to read the `config.yaml` and in not having success with it. I try with `os.Getwd` and also `ex, err := os.Executable()` and also `"../../../"` without success, any idea ?

@VonC - suggested to use `https://github.com/gobuffalo/packr` which can help I guess but the problem is that I need to call it inside the `fs.go` file and I need to pass this as parameter **from** the `main.go` file, is there a better approach  ? because I need to pass this parameter in lots of functions...

does `viper` can help? https://github.com/spf13/viper

My program is `CLI` program which will be used as `bin`.

Answer (score -1):

2018: If the binary is built in `GOPATH/bin`, while your sources are in `GOPATH/src`, then the relative path would be (at runtime) `../src/myproject`.

But a cleaner way would be to embed that file in your binary.
See for instance [`gobuffalo/packr`](https://github.com/gobuffalo/packr).

---

Update Q1 2021: with Go 1.16, you would use the [`embed` package](https://golang.org/pkg/embed/)

> Go source files that `import "embed"` can use the `//go:embed` directive to initialize a variable of type `string`, `[]byte`, or `FS` with the contents of files read from the package directory or subdirectories at compile time.

```golang
//go:embed hello.txt
var f embed.FS
data, _ := f.ReadFile("hello.txt")
print(string(data))
```

Comment: Thanks, this is a `cli `project which I need to provide as `bin`.. but why I need to use external package , the yaml file is part of my binary...part of my project...

Comment: @JennyM The yaml file is part of your project sources, but not your binary (which can be executed from any path). Embedding the yaml resource in the binary makes said executable autonomous.

Comment: ok, so in case I need to use `packr` and I have this project structure, how would you use it in my context ?

Comment: so in my case it should be like this `box := packr.NewBox("./../../config.yaml") ` . ??

Comment: @JennyM https://github.com/gobuffalo/packr#what-is-a-box: a box is a folder, not a file. "`./../..`"

Comment: still not sure how to use it :(, can you please provide example ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178323/discussion-between-jenny-m-and-vonc).

Comment: I want to use the packr as you suggested but since my config file is under the root is confusing , can you provide suggestion how to build the path with `packr` ?

Comment: @JennyM I suggested  "./../.." (relative path from where the binary is, assuming GOPATH/bin. But that need to be tested.

Comment: this will not work since when I print `os.getwd` (just for tracing) I got the path of the project which run my project (my project is cli tool) and I got `/Users/i0354436/go/src/userapp`

Comment: I print it `os.getwd` to see the path when user run my `bin`

Comment: @JennyM OK, try other relative path for testing. I don't have much more than what is explained in https://github.com/gobuffalo/packr#usage

Comment: last question :) assume that I need the opposite ,i.e. the file is located in the root and in sub package I need to access it, what will be the box here ?

Comment: @JennyM I suppose relative to the subpackage, as in https://github.com/gobuffalo/packr/issues/82

Comment: so you think that if my project called `myproject` and the `config.yaml` file is under it, this should be like `configBox := packr.NewBox("./")` or `configBox := packr.NewBox("./myproject")`

Comment: @JennyM one of those two, yes: you can test both.

Comment: Thank you i'll try